# I want to post data from HTML file to php and how to redirect to the php and show data in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I would like to post data from the html file to the php file and how to redirect to the php file and see the data in the console page.

I am a beginner and not very good in ajax. Please check below code I have used.

I want to send json data to the php file. My question is how to post json data to php and see the data in php file. I got error which states undefined index postcountry.

My another question is how to solve the error. Please help me correct the mistake.

Thank you.

In ajax.html

```
    <html>
     <head>
     <title> NEW AJAX</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-
     1.11.3.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <h2>Show Data in PHP</h2>
      <br />
      <br />
      <form>
       <input type="hidden" id="country" value="singapore" readonly>
       <input type="hidden" id="time" value="141253" readonly>
       <input type="button" value="submit me" onlcick="showData();">
      </form>


    <div id="resulte"></div>
    <h3>Look at the console. Click Ctrl + Shift + J to VIEW THE CONSOLE PAGE.
    </H3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var country = document.getElementById("country");
     var time = document.getElementById("time");
     function showData() {
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType:  "json",
         url: "abdullahpass.php",
        //async: false,
         data: JSON.stringfy({postcountry: country,
         posttime: time}),
         success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);  
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or 
            Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
            $('#resulte').html('<p>Status Code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p>
            <p>ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p>
            <div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
            console.log('jqXHR:');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log('textStatus:');
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log('errorThrown:');
            console.log(errorThrown);
          },
       });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In another file

```
      <?php
         echo json_decode($_POST['posttime']);
         echo json_decode($_POST['postcountry']);
         echo var_dump($_POST);
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

//In your  ajax call `data` no need to `strigyfy` data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var country = document.getElementById("country");
         var time = document.getElementById("time");
         function showData() {
           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             dataType:  "json",
             url: "abdullahpass.php",
            //async: false,
             data: {postcountry: country,posttime: time},
             success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);  
             },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or 
                Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
                $('#resulte').html('<p>Status Code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p>
                <p>ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p>
                <div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
                console.log('jqXHR:');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('textStatus:');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:');
                console.log(errorThrown);
              },
           });
        }
        </script>
```

**I got error which states undefined index postcountry** is not error its a warning, Using `isSet` function you can overcome the same and $_POST['posttime'] and $_POST['postcountry'] are values. You should to use `json_encode` on array only.

```
    <?php

         echo (isSet($_POST['posttime']) && $_POST['posttime']) ? $_POST['posttime'] : 'No value for posttime';
         echo (isSet($_POST['postcountry']) && $_POST['postcountry']) ? $_POST['postcountry'] : 'No value for postcountry';


         //this will print total post data with type
         echo var_dump($_POST);
      ?>
```

Comment: thank you for correcting my mistake. But I want to view the values in php. The values for postcountry and posttime are empty....

Comment: Why are the values empty???? I want to get the values from AJAX post in php and write the values to the file.

Comment: check in console what data posting

Comment: I am not able to see any data when I click the submit button

Comment: can you please update what you changed in question??

Comment: My question is why the values for the two variables are empty. How to get those values after you performed the ajax post in the php??

Comment: This is my first time using this forum.... What should I modify if I want to get the values for those two variables in the php after I clicked the submit button??

Comment: what ever you doing is correct only......alert country,time before send is data populated or not

Comment: I know that I am doing correctly. But how to make it so that I can see the values for the posttime and postcountry in the php script..

Comment: abdullahpass.php

Comment: can you please only add  echo json_encode($_POST);die; and check it....

Comment: i added the code which you told me.. The script states '[]'.  No values..